# How to write a generic method to count the number of palindromes in an array?

Tags: java, generics

I want to write a generic method that takes an array of integers and counts how many of them are palindrome.

Here is my program:

```
public class pal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] a = {12131,121,324,123,33,43,5654};

        System.out.println("Total palindromes : "+checkPalindrome(a));

        }

        public static <T> int checkPalindrome(T[] b){
            int n=0,temp=0,sum=0,r=0;
            for(T a:b){
                temp = (int)a;
                while((int)a>0){
                    r = (int)a%10;
                    sum = (sum*10)+r;
                }
                if(temp == sum){
                    n++;
                }
            }
            return n;
        }
    }
```

The code doesn't throw any exception nor does it do anything.

Comment: Why do you need the function to be generic.? An array of integers should be enough (knowing that you cast the elements to int inside the function.

Comment: for university test

Comment: Also consider `Array.asList()`, a "bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs."

Comment: meh,,,,fixed it

Comment: why are you writhing a generic method only to cast the results to int inside of the function?  That seems redundant and a good place for a whole host of errors.

Comment: because my faculty wants it this way

Comment: It doesn't make sense. A generic method is supposed to work with any type. Is `new Object()` a palindrome? I suspect you're miscommunicating the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class pali{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] a = {12131,121,324,123,33,43,5654,45654};

        System.out.println("Total palindromes : "+checkPalindrome(a));

        }

        public static <T> int checkPalindrome(T[] b){

            int n=0;

            for(T a:b){
                int sum=0,r=0;
                int temp = (int)a;
                int k = (int)a;

                while(k!=0){
                    r = k%10;
                    sum = (sum*10)+r;
                    k/=10;
                }
                if(temp == sum) 
                n++;
            }

            return n;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `Integer` values to strings, and utilize the `StringBuilder.reverse` method to validate a palindrome.

```java
static int checkPalindrome(Integer[] values) {
    StringBuilder string;
    int count = 0;
    for (Integer value : values) {
        string = new StringBuilder(value.toString());
        if (string.reverse().toString().equals(value.toString()))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```